# FileStream WriteAsync and await confusion

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, async-await

I'm looking at the new `async` and `await` keywords in C# and just trying to get a feel for them.

I'm looking at the MSDN `FileStream.WriteAsync()` [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158629.aspx), and I wasn't sure I understood something.

The example is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnicodeEncoding uniencoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            string filename = @"c:\Users\exampleuser\Documents\userinputlog.txt";

            byte[] result = uniencoding.GetBytes(UserInput.Text);

            using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                SourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                await SourceStream.WriteAsync(result, 0, result.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't get is the placement of the `await`. It seems that you can't take the `Task` item that is returned by `WriteAsync()` because this always gives me a syntax error. So the only way I could get this to compile is by leaving the `await` with the call.

But if you do this, does it not wait for the call to finish? This makes it not very asynchronous...

Comment: What do you mean by "take" the `Task` item?

Comment: @Jon Something like `Task t = SourceStream.WriteAsync(result, 0, result.Length);` and later on do `await t;`

Comment: You can definitely do that - what makes you think you can't?

Comment: @JonSkeet - You're right... I was being a fool and messing something else up...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with your understanding of what `await` does.

> But if you do this, does it not wait for the call to finish? This makes it not very asynchronous...

When you `await` something, you "block asynchronously" - your asynchronous function will continue when the asynchronous operation has completed, but the immediate call will complete immediately.

So in your case, the UI thread becomes unblocked because `Button_Click` returns, but when the file write operation has completed, execution will return (still in the UI thread) to the end of the `await` expression... you'll then close the `FileStream` and complete the asynchronous function.

It would be clearer what was going on if you did something else *after* the `await` expression (e.g. updating the UI). But yes, it really *is* asynchronous - it just allows you to write code which *looks* synchronous.

Comment: So lets say I did some method `doWork()` after the `await`, the method wouldn't get called until AFTER the write has finished?

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed. But while your asynchronous function was waiting for that to complete, it *wouldn't* be holding up the UI thread. It's like ordering a pizza - you can't *eat* the pizza until it's been delivered, but you can do other things instead :)

Comment: @Andrew you had me at pizza!

Answer (score 2):

The await doesn't actually block while it's waiting. What happens is that the compiler does some complex stuff to make a so called continuation of all code after the await and tells the task to execute that continuation when it's completed.

Basically the last lines of the Button_Click method are translated to:

```
FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
SourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
Task t = SourceStream.WriteAsync(result, 0, result.Length);
t.ContinueWith(_ => SourceStream.Dispose());
```

Of course, this is simplified as this will be executed more efficient if the WriteAsync completes immediately, for example.